# JQuery-UI not referencing

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, express, ejs

Ahoy!

I have a JSFiddle where the code runs and executes perfectly fine referencing JQuery (1.9.1), JQuery UI (1.9.2), Bootstrap (2.3.1) onDOMready.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Xsmx/

I then copy and paste the `<div>` to my project in an EJS file (there is no changes to the  inserted).

I make the following calls in the header:

```html
 <link href="/netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/globalstylesheet.css">
```

/
Footer:

```html
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/userdashboard.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The slider now no longer appears and the following doesn't exist (where as it does in the JSFiddle).

```html
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: -41px; left: -19px; display: block;">    
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">10</div></div>
```

I can see no references to JQuery-UI where as in the JSFiddle google dev tools, I can see various references. Everything else on the page, css, bootstrap etc, is running fine, just the control slider.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: I think, you should import jquery.js before bootstrap.js. It sometimes causes some troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alesh, I'll keep that in mind, sadly I changed it to this order in an attempt to fix the issue. Neither way seemed to work.